# How can i add the WSDL of the Amazon Product Advertising API to a Visual Studio console application

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, soap, wsdl

I know that i can Right click to the Project => References => Add => ServiceReference ...

When i do that, i get the Service Reference but some classes are missing. 
For example AWSECommerceService.

The Amazon examples seems to be outdated.

Thank you for your help

WSDL: http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl?rw_useCurrentProtocol=1

Comment: A c# project to be exactly

Answer (score 0):

The have renamed the AWSECommerceService class to AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient

[Search amazon example with new amazon service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142909/search-amazon-example-with-new-amazon-service)